# angular application is cached when using auto suggest url in Firefox

Tags: angularjs, caching

When the application is accessed through auto suggest url of firefox, it loads the cached version of index html. 
But as soon as the user re-loads the page, it loads the latest version of index html properly.

I have used meta tags which is mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1341133/1822974).

Can we do something in javascript to completely disable cache?

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the caching in your routes by using `cache: false`.

```
$stateProvider.state('yourState', {
   cache: false,
   url : '/yourUrl',
   templateUrl : 'yourTemplate.html',
   ...
});
```

Another way to force the reloading of your pages is to add a query param in each of your call (I do it in my services). It will be interpreted as a new URL.

For example: `return '/home?' + Math.random();`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But the problem is, the new javascript will not be loaded as the index html itself is cached. just for example, my current index html has `<script src="base/application.js?v=3.0.0"/>` but the browser still loads `<script src="base/application.js?v=2.7.3"/>`. In this case, the above solution does not work for me:(

Comment: You can also do my trick on script loading: `<script src="base/application.js?v=3.0.0?{BUILD_NUMBER}"/>`. Set `BUILD_NUMBER` as `Math.random()`.